# Docker Container from Terraform will not start

Tags: docker, terraform

I launched a Docker container with Terraform, simple code.

```
> cat main.tf
provider "docker"{

}

resource "docker_image" "ubuntu"{
    name = "ubuntu:latest"
}

resource "docker_container" "webserver" {
    image = "${docker_image.ubuntu.latest}"
    name = "dev-web-p01"
    #start = true
    must_run = true
    publish_all_ports = true
}
```

I can see the container spun up but not running.

```sh
> docker container -ps -a
CONTAINER ID     IMAGE           COMMAND        CREATED          STATUS                     PORTS           NAMES
63c770e28ad2     47b19964fb50    "/bin/bash"    10 minutes ago   Exited (0) 3 minutes ago                   dev-web-p01
```

My attempt to start and connect to the container fails and I am not sure why?

```sh
> docker container start 63c
63c

> docker container exec -it 63c /bin/bash
Error response from daemon: Container 63c770e28ad256e77442cb2fb8b9b8bbc14b8f37b99296bc63f2d249209e0399 is not running
```

I have tried this for a couple of times but it doesn't work. Sorry bit of a noob here.

Comment: Terraform doesn't accept image files as input, so it's very hard to try out your setup.  Can you edit this question to have the _text_ of your `.tf` file and the text output of the various commands, instead of screenshots of terminal windows?

Comment: I also recommend the [official Docker tutorial on building and running custom images](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part2/), and build an image with the application you want to run in it.  Running a bare `ubuntu` image is extremely uninteresting and will basically always behave this way.

Comment: Please don't post images -- copy and paste the text instead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Exited (0)` means program successfully completed. With docker you need to execute some long running commands to ensure it doesn't finish immediately.

Best way to test some changes with docker, is waiting for nothing. Try this:

```
resource "docker_image" "ubuntu" {
  name = "ubuntu:latest"
}
resource "docker_container" "webserver" {
  image = "${docker_image.ubuntu.latest}"
  name = "terraform-docker-test"
  must_run = true
  publish_all_ports = true
  command = [
    "tail",
    "-f",
    "/dev/null"
  ]
}
```